# The time left for the map is not on my HUD, how do I put it back?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I've been screwing around with the game console (I'll never do that again) and now the time limit of the match isn't showing up for me on any map, can you help me and tell me the command to to enable it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've fixed it! I had other crap in my custom folder, and I deleted it all except the read me file, and now the time shows.

Answer (score 0):

If you altered the size of your window, or switched it from "Run Fullscreen" to "Run In Windowed Mode", it's possible your Timer was covered up by the change in size.  If this is the case, it's usually fixed by restarting TF2.  You may also have to manually adjust the resolution size of your screen, and if you are using a custom HUD, it could be even more complicated depending upon which HUD you use (though most will adjust to the new screen size automatically).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried changing it to run in windowed mode, but the clock isn't there, I also tried re downloading tf2 and got the same result, but how do you restart tf2?

Comment: @Michael Just closing and opening the game is what I meant.  Also, try switching from Windowed to Full-Screen.  If it doesn't work, then this answer is probably not going to work for you.

Comment: My console always says this: Game server authentication: FAILURE!
   No such game account, could that be a clue?

Comment: @Michael That sounds significantly worse than just not being able to see the timer on your map.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Michael No, but it sounds like you figured it out.  Sorry I couldn't help more.